# How do you vertically center text and hide the overflown text?

Tags: css

The typical solution to vertically center text is:

```
p {
    width: 10em;
    height: 2.4em;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

The effect is:

```
 _________________
|                 |
|                 |
| Line 1 of text  |
|                 |
|_________________|

 _________________
|                 |
| Line 1 of text  |
| Line 2 of text  |
| Line 3 of text  |
|_________________|
```

This solution did not work for me when I attempt to hide text that is too long to fit into the box:

```
p {
    ...
    ...
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

The overflow rule is ignored for some reason for table cells.

```
 _________________
| Line 1 of text  |
| Line 2 of text  |
| Line 3 of text  |
| Line 4 of text  |
| Line 5 of text  |
 -----------------
  Line 6 of text
  Line 7 of text
```

Many other rules stop working too, including margin. Is there any other way to vertically center an arbitrary number of lines of text without breaking so many other critical CSS rules?

Comment: Can you post a complete code example and a jsFiddle?

Comment: Basically you can use a div-container with relative positioning and another div inside this container with absolute positioning to center items horizontally and vertically. See this article on "Center Anything with CSS": <http://designshack.net/articles/css/how-to-center-anything-with-css/>

Comment: @kleinfreund Your method works for static width elements. If the text container needs to be liquid, it won't work because `display:table-cell` is inline and invalidates `width:100%`.

Comment: Do you still have to use `display: table-cell;` then? In my opinion this would be the same as using real tables.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays there is a great solution using flexbox available for this problem. I have prepared a code snippet:

```css
div {
    width: 10em;
    height: 2.4em;
  
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
  
    background: blue;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      asjdg<br>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div>
      asjdg<br>
      asdsad<br>
      asdh<br>
      asdhsjkadh<br>
      asgdh<br>
      asdasd<br>
      asdasd<br>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know this question is 5 years old but has no answer. Maybe future googlers will find help.